# Refresh JTable after adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable that's filled with the inventory data of a garage. It has parts, number in storage etc. At this moment i have a JOptionPane where you can enter the data if you want to add a new part to the inventory. that works fine but how do i refresh the JTable data after the part is added?

This is the code I use to fille the table initially :

```
private String[] kolommenOnderdelen = { "Nr", "Omschrijving", "Vooraad" };
private DefaultTableModel modelOnderdelen = new DefaultTableModel(kolommenOnderdelen, 0);

    for (Onderdeel a : voorraad.alleOnderdelen()) {
        modelOnderdelen.addRow(new String[] {
                Integer.toString(a.getOnderdeelNummer()),
                a.getOnderdeelOmschrijving(),
                Integer.toString(a.getOnderdeelVoorraad()) });
    }

    tabelOnderdelen = new JTable(modelOnderdelen)
```

and this is the code I have for the JOptionPane

```
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, nieuwOnderdeel,
                "Voer de gegevens van het nieuwe onderdeel in",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            if (!onderdeelOmschrijving.getText().equals("")
                    && !onderdeelNR.getText().equals("")
                    && !onderdeelVoorraad.getText().equals("")) {
                if (voorraad.voegOnderdeelToe(new Onderdeel(
                        onderdeelOmschrijving.getText(), Integer
                                .parseInt(onderdeelNR.getText()), Integer
                                .parseInt(onderdeelVoorraad.getText())))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Het onderdeel is toegevoegd");
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Niet volledig ingevuld", "Vul alle gegevens in!",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to call `modelOnderdelen.addRow(..)` when you want to add a new row

Comment: Please update your question to show the type of `modelOnderdelen`, likely `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: I think this makes it more clear how @nachokk's answer applies.

Comment: @trashgod that's true.. i should put.. assuming that you are using DefaultTableModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the new row to the tableModel as you did when you init the table.
Using `modelOnderdelen.addRow(..)` will work, this will notify listeners (the view) and the new row will be shown in JTable.